# How do I initialise view controller with custom data?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using `present` to open a view controller.

```
self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboard", bundle: nil)
self.myView = self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController() as? myViewController
self.present(self.myView!, animated: true) { _ in }
```

Then in the view controller I'm trying to get data from initialiser

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {

    var dataA: String?
    var dataB: String?

    override init(dataA: String, dataB: String) {
        self.dataA = dataA
        self.dataB = dataB
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

I get an error `Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass`

How should I override `init` and pass data in this case?

Comment: The / a custom initializer is not called at all when calling `instantiateInitialViewController()`. Is there a particular reason to instantiate the initial view controller programmatically ?

Comment: When loading a viewcontroller from storyboard, initWithCoder gets called. Why dont you create a method to take your data and call it after instantiating viewcontroller from storyboard?

Comment: @vadian I'm following an example to write a Cordova plugin for my hybrid app. Not sure if this is the right way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is a way, other than not using storyboards. Even Swinject does that in a separate method.

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {

    var dataA: String?
    var dataB: String?

    fun initialize(dataA: String, dataB: String) {
        self.dataA = dataA
        self.dataB = dataB
    }
}
```

and in the other class

```
self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboard", bundle: nil)
self.myView = self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController() as? myViewController
self.myView.initialize(dataA: dataA, dataB: dataB)
self.present(self.myView!, animated: true) { _ in }
```

---

or you can do it in other way and create a static func, that will return an instance. But I prefer the first way.

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {

    var dataA: String?
    var dataB: String?

    static func instance(dataA: String, dataB: String) -> myViewController {
        //You could pass storyboard too
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboard", bundle: nil)

        let myView = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? myViewController
        self.dataB = dataB
        self.dataA = dataA

        return myView
    }
}
```